# how to remove the numbers followed by a dot(.) in a given line

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I want to remove the numbers followed by dot ( irrespective of no of digits) from the line.

```
echo "99.1DEEP CHA/SM  9.1DEEP CHA/SM  123.1DEEP CHA/SM" | sed 's|[0-9]\.||g'
```

Actual Result :

```
 91DEEP CHA/SM  1DEEP CHA/SM  121DEEP CHA/SM
```

Expected result :

```
1DEEP CHA/SM  1DEEP CHA/SM  1DEEP CHA/SM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `[0-9]\.` you are searching for 1 digit followed by a `.`. If you want to search for all digits followed by a `.`, then use `[0-9]\+\.`

```
echo "99.1DEEP CHA/SM  9.1DEEP CHA/SM  123.1DEEP CHA/SM" | sed 's|[0-9]\+\.||g'
```

Output

```
1DEEP CHA/SM  1DEEP CHA/SM  1DEEP CHA/SM
```